# SQL Server search and orderby

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search in SQL Server. When I enter "A bang", and use "Like '%A bang%'", and order by ...

I want to arrange to results with words starting with "A bang" , after that the results contain "A bang" but not start word.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CLNTPFX ASC, CLNTCOY ASC,
                                     SURNAME ASC, GIVNAME ASC,
                                     CLNTNUM ASC, UNIQUE_NUMBER DESC) ROWN,
         TEMP1.*
     FROM 
         (SELECT *
          FROM CLNTPF
          WHERE CLNTPFX = 'CN'
            AND CLNTCOY = '9'
            AND SURNAME LIKE 'A Bang'
            AND VALIDFLAG = 1) TEMP1) TEMP2
WHERE 
    ROWN > 12
    AND ROWN <= 24
```

Example expected when search "O"

```
Owner                         
Owner                         
Owner                         
Owner                         
Owner                         
A Owner
A Owner
A Owner
```

May you help me?

Thanks all!

Comment: Share the output of the above mentioned query and your expected result.

Comment: Example expected when search "O" :
Owner
Owner
Owner
Owner
A Owner A Owner A Owner

Comment: add some more sample data & desired o/p, so we could suggest the solutions according it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `c1` is the column on which you want to sort your data in a way that the words starting with `O` appear first, then followed by words having `O` somewhere in text, then followed by all other words, You can add an `order by` to your query as below.

```
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN c1 LIKE 'O%'
            THEN 1
        WHEN c1 LIKE '%O%'
            THEN 2
        ELSE 3 end;
```

On your sample data, below is the result.

```
C1
------------------------
Owner
Owner
Owner
Owner
A Owner 
A Owner 
A Owner
```

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/OWR46707)**